# Where can I find audio recordings of every word?

Tags: pronunciation, resources, database, audio

Where can I find audio recordings (i.e. individual MP3s or WAVs) for every Chinese word? I have found some recordings of Chinese, but these only contain individual phonemes, not entire words. I am looking for something to download or as something to buy (e.g. as part of a dictionary).

Comment: *every* Chinese word?

Comment: Or at least every combination of phonemes that typically forms a two, three, or four-character words.

Answer (score 8):

For example, you can go to [Forvo.com](http://www.forvo.com). (You can find the Chinese section at [this address](http://www.forvo.com/languages/zh/); on the right you see the top users that provided most audios.)

It's a huge database of words, characters, expressions in any language provided by users. The good thing is there's a lot of stuff, but the down-side is that although some users provided many audios (so you have a sort of consistency), you'll have to switch between different audios not recorded professionally, although they usually are not low quality.

Comment: In addition, when a word does not have a recording, you can request one. In my experience, the new recording will become available within a day.

Answer (score 2):

[mdbg.net](http://mdbg.net)

Each of the words you look up in the dictionary there comes complete with an audio recording.

Comment: I tried searching for "你好吗", but it gives only the three readings in sequence, not one recording of the sentence... Or did I miss the feature?

Comment: If you are looking for the sentence together, then [link](http://translate.google.com/) will read it to you. Just click the speaker icon.

Answer (score 1):

Another web site is http://www.iciba.com where you can find not only the pronunciation of Chinese characters and words, but also their meaning in English and Chinese.

**Update**

This site has real person readings, but unfortunately the site is totally in Chinese:

> http://www.caca8.net/zi/py/ — single characters
>   http://www.caca8.net/ci/ — words
>   http://www.caca8.net/chy/ — idioms

Comment: The pronunciation at this site appears to be made of individually recorded phonemes that are simply played close together, so it is not very natural.

Comment: Nice update by the way... I can't understand the site since it's in Chinese, but can you look if there's a mention whether the audios are downloadable or not? Thanks.

Comment: @Alenanno The pronunciations are in flash files, so it's really difficult to download the audio files if not possible. But they have a free desktop version of the dictionary can be downloaded from http://www.onlinedown.net/soft/109615.htm

Comment: The files can be downloaded -- technically, if maybe not legally -- with this pattern URL: http://www.caca8.net/fayin/XXXXXX.mp3 where XXXXXX is the pinyin (a1, ba2, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Google Translate. To get downloads in mp3 format, see responses to this [Stack Exchange question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163988/download-mp3-from-google-translate-text-to-speech/13823866#13823866).